# Confused ERROR revelant to C pointer: Expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have (pointer-to-) function type

Tags: c, pointers

I am a beginner in Data Structure with C language, and this is what I met when learning sequential queue:

```
typedef struct {
    int NO;
    int ST; //starttime
} CAR; //car struct    

typedef struct {
    CAR* sqqbase; // sqqueue's base
    int front;
    int rear;
} SQQ; // sequential queue

int InitQueue(SQQ *sqq)
{
    (*sqq).sqqbase = (CAR*)malloc(SQQMAXSIZE*sizeof(CAR))
    (*sqq).frint = (*sqq).rear=0;
    return 0;
}
```

I think the types of all the variables should be correct, but on line 73 of the third pic, it alerts that"**Expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have (pointer-to-) function type"**. Now  I don't know how to tackle this error, could you give me some advice?

Comment: Don't post links to pictures of text. Post text as properly formatted text. Read this: [ask] and this: [mcve]. Then [edit] the question. After that you'll certainly get an answer.

Comment: Post the code as text...

Comment: Do you have `#include <stdlib.h>` in the .c file that contains the call to `malloc`?

Comment: You need to distinguish between messages from your IDE and from the compiler. The former is little more than an aid, but the latter is relevant. What does your compiler say when you try to compile? Remember to raise the warning level to the maximum. (Hint: good compilers recognize the name of the function and tell you about the missing include.)

Comment: This sounds as if the compiler/IDE not just complains about missing declaration of `malloc` but thinks it is something different than a function. Do you have an own definition of `malloc`? As long as you don't update your question to replace the images with a complete code example (as text) we can only guess.

Answer (score 0):

Looks as if the code doesn't know `malloc` to be a function. Please note that in C, no function is known to the compiler unless you tell the compiler about it; this also holds true for all functions of the C standard API. Usually this is done by declaring functions in header files and then including the header files where you want the functions to be known. E.g. the compiler won't know that a function named `malloc` exists, unless you include `<stdlib.h>` into a source file as that's where `malloc` is declared.